# How can I plot a graph on an opaque surface in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to draw some points on the surface of a sphere. For my purposes, I need to be able to plot lines around the three dimensional sphere. The sphere shall be opaque, such that in the view one can only see the points on the visible half of the sphere. Currently I am just plotting the points with the following snippet:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = 1 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 1 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 1 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride =5,
    cstride = 5, color ='yellow')
plt.plot(CatVec[:,0],CatVec[:,1],CatVec[:,2],'ro')
```

This give me the following plot:
[image: 3D plot with a line that goes around the sphere once. Only 50% of the points should be visible.]

Unfortunately, all points are visible. Also those that are actually on the backside of the sphere.

**How can I make the sphere opaque, such that only the points on the facing side of the sphere are visible?**

Comment: What if you plot the points first and then the surface?

Comment: That does not change anything, but thanks for the thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easy to do with matplotlib due to the way that the 3D graphs are rendered.  There is not *true* 3D support, there is just code to generate a projection from 3D down to 2D. This works great for single artists and can cover a lot of use cases, however the way that the artist is drawn to the canvas means that one artist is *always* on top of the other, there is no way to have the artists switch order in some places.

You can *sort of* work around this by doing the splitting 'by hand' and plotting your functions peice wise with the correct order (see [How to draw intersecting planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this/14825951#14825951)), however this means you can not rotate out of some small viewing angle and have things look 'right'.

I would recommend looking into [mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/) which is an openGL based plotting package that can do true 3D.

Comment: Thank you very much tcaswell! I will investigate that package.

Answer (score 0):

Whats about to use Mollweide projection?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#some hints from here http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Maps

import os
import sys
import numpy
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
m=Basemap(projection='moll',lon_0=0,resolution='c')

m.drawmeridians(arange(0, 360, 30))
m.drawparallels(arange(-90, 90, 30))

lats=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.float)
lons=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.float)

lats[0] = 0; lats[1]=30; lats[2]=60
lons[0] = 0; lons[1]=30; lons[2]=-30

x,y = m(lons,lats)

plt.plot(x,y,'r')

plt.savefig('a.ps')
close()
```