# matplotlib: filling under line in 3d polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to plot a sine wave on a circle: that is, the circle is in the x,y-plane and the sine wave wraps around it perpendicular to that plane (sticking up the z-axis). I can do this, but when I try to fill the areas between the circle and the sine wave with a polygon (ie paint on the surface of the imaginary cylinder on which my sine wave lives), I can't get it quite right - matplotlib seems to XOR the regions that overlap in a view of the plot instead of giving me a view in which the ones in front occlude those behind.
Here's the relevant bit of my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax._axis3don = False
theta = np.linspace(0., 2 * np.pi, 1000)
r = 1.
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
sinez = N * np.sin(theta * m)
ax.plot(x, y, sinez, color='r')
xv = np.append(x, x[::-1])
yv = np.append(y, y[::-1])
zv = np.append(sinez, np.zeros(n))
verts = [zip(xv,yv,zrev),]
poly = Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolors = [cc('r'), cc('b')],
                        edgecolor='None')
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly)
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`matplotlib`'s main reason for existence is 2D plotting, the 3D stuff is just some clever transforms and can be buggy/hacky.  One of the inherent limitations is that `matplotlib` draws in layers, so it has no notion of 'in front' or 'behind', it only knows the order in which in draws the curves to the canvas (which is confusingly called z-order).

If you want to get this to look right with out re-writing the 3D code, split the sine wave up into pieces and make sure you set the z-order right by hand (see [How to draw intersecting planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this/14825951#14825951) for a simpler version of this), but you won't be able to rotate the image.

If you need real 3D, I would suggest looking into `mayavi` [from enthought](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/http://) which is OpenGL based.

Answer (score 1):

In the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection), the devs claim that `Poly3DCollection`

> does a bit of magic with the _facecolors and _edgecolors properties.

which I believe is the XOR effect that you can see here, and looking at the [code](http://matplotlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.99.1.2-3ubuntu1/classmpl__toolkits_1_1mplot3d_1_1art3d_1_1Poly3DCollection_cada07db4b21fcddd570da6f2163cb82.html#cada07db4b21fcddd570da6f2163cb82) it's the function `do_3d_projection` that seems to be doing the magic.

As I see it, you could either subclass `Poly3DCollection` and rewrite `do_3d_projection` to get what you want, or maybe think of another way to plot this (perhaps treating the sinusoid and circle as separate objects somehow).

Comment: Ah, the immortal matplotlib docs. I wonder what sort of "magic" is involved. Not sure I'm up to the job of editing the matplotlib source, but I notice that the XOR effect only occurs for loops on the same side of my circle, so maybe I should change the direction in which the polygons are defined.