# Matplotlib: Why is plot_surface not opaque despite "alpha=1"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Running the code below (Python 3, matplotlib 2.0.2), I get the following output:

[image]

I would prefer, and expect, the graph to cover some of the paths below it. What is going wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
paths = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=(10,10)),axis=0)
ax=plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(np.tile(range(10),(10,1)).T,paths)
N=30
Y = np.linspace(-5,5, N) 
X = np.linspace(0,10,N)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
ZZ = YY**2
ax.plot_surface(XX, YY, ZZ, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I guess this is the usual [My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not saying it isn't, but just to be clear: The output looks wrong from each and every angle, i.e. the paths are never covered at all, from any angle

Comment: I guess they all intersect the surface at some point or another, so the problem will inevitably occur for *every* viewing angle.

Comment: Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699494/how-to-obscure-a-line-behind-a-surface-plot-in-matplotlib) the idea can be to calculate which points lie in front for a given viewing angle and restrict plotting of those points.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the problem also occurs if I shift the surface to lie strictly above the paths

Comment: (in the graph that I posted, the paths never intersect, but touch the surface tangentially. anyway, the problem persists even when I lift the surface by ZZ=YY**2+10

Comment: Sorry, by intersect I mean intersect in the projected image, not intersect in true 3d space.