# Matplotlib 3D effects not overlapping correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know how to make the arrow from the image in this post appear correctly? In places where the sphere should be behind the arrow, it appears in front. Not sure if this is a limitation of Matplotlib, but help would be greatly appreciated!

[See image here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140163/python-matplotlib-plotting-a-3d-cube-a-sphere-and-a-vector)

Comment: This question even has its own [matplotlib 3D FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles) entry. Workarounds could look similar to the one in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699494/how-to-obscure-a-line-behind-a-surface-plot-in-matplotlib).

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your script to have a spiral wrapping around a line. Any idea how I can adjust the visible points for that? Not sure how to systematically do this