# mplot3d: Hiding a line plot `plot()` under a `plot_surface()`

Tags: matplotlib, mplot3d

**Edit: the problem I describe here no longer shows with current versions of matplotlib (2.1.1, edit made on 10 Sep 2019): most certainly a bug that has been fixed since then**

I want to have a line plot (drawn with `Axis.plot()`) that is partially covered by the surface generated by `Axis.plot_surface()`. I wrote the following script:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

resolution = 100
ax = plt.gca(projection="3d")
x, y = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, resolution) ,
                    np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, resolution) )
phi = (1.0 - x)*(1.0 - y) / 4.0
ax.plot([-1.0,1.0], [-1.0,1.0], [0.0,0.0], color="red")
ax.plot_surface(x, y, phi, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

and made sure to have the call to `plot()` before the one to `plot_surface()`. Nevertheless, it seems that the line plot always has the highest "zindex" and gets plotted over the surface. Here is what I obtain:

[image: What I've got]

Here is what I would like to have instead:[image]

How do I achieve this result? (Without using Gimp…)

Comment: I can't find the question the last time this was asked, but IIRC there is no way to do without your own raytracer that figures out how much of that line should be visible from your particular viewpoint.

Comment: Does that mean that it is either a missing feature or a bug?

Comment: For the general case this is a missing feature. See [My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles). For this special case where you only have one line and one surface, there might still be some workaround of adjusting the drawing order or [masking the line depending on the viewing angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699494/how-to-obscure-a-line-behind-a-surface-plot-in-matplotlib).

Answer (score -1):

I changed.

```
ax.plot_surface(x, y, phi, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

with:

```
ax.plot_surface(x, y, phi, linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
```

and then I saw the whole red line
[It shows the plot with red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC6Xm.png)

Comment: The goal was to **not** see the red line because it goes below the surface. But matplotlib was showing the whole of it nevertheless. That being said, I ran the code in the original post again… and it worked! Most certainly a bug that was fixed between the current version of matplotlib, and the version I had back at the time of writting the original post.