# Plotting a 3d line intersecting a surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to plot a surface and a line which is passing through it. I want to have a plot where the portion of the line which is behind the surface, is hidden.

I tried this in matplotlib but the portion of the line behind the surface is also visible.

[Line intersecting a surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zby2N.png)

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,10,1)
y = np.arange(0,10,1)
z = np.arange(0,10,1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z= np.ones((len(x),len(x)))*5

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='red', edgecolor='black')
ax1.plot(x,y,z,'-',color='black',linewidth=4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems to be a missing feature as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820881/mplot3d-hiding-a-line-plot-plot-under-a-plot-surface) by IOBE. Check out the workaround solution posted by IOBE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699494/how-to-obscure-a-line-behind-a-surface-plot-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2):

In matplotlib, there is a concept of the `zorder`. Objects with a higher `zorder` are plotted in a layer on top of objects with a lower `zorder`, as per [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html). By default, the patch has a higher `zorder` than the line, which is why your red surface appears to block out the line. Here I have created a new set of coordinates for the background and foreground parts of the line, by selecting indices where `z <= 5` or `z >= 5` respectively. Then I plot these two sets of points separately, setting the `zorder` for all three - the surface and both of the lines.

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
z = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

x_background = x[z <= 5]
y_background = y[z <= 5]
z_background = z[z <= 5]
x_foreground = x[z >= 5]
y_foreground = y[z >= 5]
z_foreground = z[z >= 5]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.ones((len(x), len(x))) * 5

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='red', edgecolor='black', zorder=1)
ax1.plot(
    z_background, z_background, z_background, '-', color='black', linewidth=4,
    zorder=2)
ax1.plot(
    z_foreground, z_foreground, z_foreground, '-', color='black', linewidth=4,
    zorder=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: Line from behind using zorder]

Hope this helps!