# Matplotlib - multiple surface plots, wrong overlapping

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib, plot

I am currently plotting two completely different datasets into one 3D surface plot. When I am plotting each one independently, everything works fine. However, as soon as I plot them in one, the visualization is strange. I do the plotting the following way:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, color=color, antialiased=True)
(get new X,Y, Z values)
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, color=color, antialiased=True)
ax.view_init(30, 360)
```

The output is the following:

[image: output]

As you can see, the blue data is correct, but the green one is somehow in the backside and not correctly visualized. If I plot the green one alone, it works perfectly.

Changing the order of plotting (or playing around with zorder) does not change anything.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: This is most likely because matplotlib was originally intended to be a pure 2D plotting library. The 3D capabilities of matplotlib are limited, as they are achieved by transformations. To plot in "real" 3D using Python, you should check out [mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use mayavi by using mesh() but the resulting plot keeps empty. I have used the same X,Y,Z numpy array as for my matplotlib code. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw diagrams like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this)

Comment: You should open a new question 'how do I do with with mayavi?'

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib is just a 2d plotting library. 3d plots are achieved by projecting the 3d surface onto the image plane.

If you have multiple 3d surfaces, it will turn each into a 2d shape, and then calculate a single height for each shape, and show then in that order.

As far as I'm aware, the zorder option doesn't work, and all it would is change the order of the surfaces anyway.

If you're really unlucky, the grey boxes that make up the axis grids can get plotted above your surface too. That's even more annoying.

Of you must use matplotlib, then i guess you could split up your surface into lots of smaller ones, but you're going to encounter a pretty big performance bit doing this, and you'll to override the values in the legend too.

Comment: be careful about 'height' vs 'zorder'.  Each 3D surface is projected and rendered sequentially -> you can never have a crossing.