# matplotlib not displaying intersection of 3D planes correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I want to plot two planes and find their intersection line, but I get this result, where it's impossible to tell where they intersect, because one plane overlays the other.

A 3D projection should hide the non-visible part of the plane, how do I attain this result using **matplotlib**?

[image: planes]

You can clearly see that these to plains *should* intersect.

[image: plane intersect]

Here's the code I've used to get this result

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

values = range(-10, 11)

def plotPlane(plot, normal, d, values, colorName):
    # x, y, z
    x, y = np.meshgrid(values, values)
    z = (-normal[0] * x - normal[1] * y - d) * 1. / normal[2]

    # draw plot
    plot.plot_surface(x, y, z, color=colorName)

image = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')

plotPlane(image, [3, 2, -4], 1, values, "red")
plotPlane(image, [5, -1, 2], 4, values, "gray")

plt.show()
```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608098/432913).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [How to draw intersecting planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this/14825951#14825951) for a long explanation + possible work around.

The short answer in that matplotlib's 3D support is clever use of projections to generate a 2D view of the 3D object which is then rendered to the canvas.  Due to the way that matplotlib renders (artist at a time) one artist is either fully above or fully below another.  If you need real 3D support look into `mayavi`.

Comment: Thanks! I've took a huge detour into MATLAB, as far as I can tell, it's straight 3D. But I'll check out mayavi too.

Comment: I am confused, where did MATLAB come into this?

Comment: matplotlib is a tool, MATLAB is a tool, so I'm just switching tools.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608098/432913) answer i posted a while ago is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 8):

Use [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/). You will get an interactive plot which you will be able to snapshot at any angle.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from typing import Tuple, Iterable


def plotPlane(fig: go.Figure,
              normal: Tuple[int, int, int],
              d: int,
              values: Iterable,
              colorScaleName: str) -> None:
    """
        :param fig: figure to plot on
        :param colorScaleName: choose from <https://plotly.com/javascript/colorscales/>
    """
    # x, y, z
    x, y = np.meshgrid(values, values)
    z = (-normal[0] * x - normal[1] * y - d) * 1. / normal[2]

    # draw plane
    surface = go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale=colorScaleName, showscale=False)
    fig.add_trace(surface, row=1, col=1)


# create figure
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1, specs=[[{'type': 'surface'}]])
# plot two intersectioned surfaces
values = range(-10, 11)
plotPlane(fig, (3, 2, -4), 1, values, "Hot")
plotPlane(fig, (5, -1, 2), 4, values, "Greys")
fig.show()
```

I ran it in jupyter-notebbok.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Epic example! But please add `from plotly.subplots import make_subplots`