# Plotting 2d slices of 3d data in python (preferably using matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to plot 2d slices of 3d data as shown in this figure ([image: 2d slices of 3d data goes here]). Is it possible to do it in python, preferably using matplotlib? I am hoping to have someone provide me with guidance, or a sample code is even better. I appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Matplotlib so far can not handle the intersecting planes correctly.

[matplotlib not displaying intersection of 3D planes correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407936/matplotlib-not-displaying-intersection-of-3d-planes-correctly)

[Display the maximum surface in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531752/display-the-maximum-surface-in-matplotlib/28608098#28608098)

You can try to use [mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/) or [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/). In particular check out [this link](https://nbviewer.org/github/empet/Plotly-plots/blob/master/Plotly-Slice-in-volumetric-data.ipynb)