# Strange zorder behavior in matplotlib 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a zorder problem with an example in the matplotlib 3d gallery.  It's this example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches((20,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], list(10*np.arange(4))):
        xs = np.arange(20)
        ys = np.random.rand(20)
        cs = [c] * len(xs)
        ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

Here, the zordering is as expected: the foreground histograms are on top of the background ones.  On the other hand, if I modify the example ever so slightly --- just increase the number of histograms --- I get something weird.  The zorder is jumbled for some of the bars in the histograms.  The offending code is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches((20,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], list(10*np.arange(8))):
        xs = np.arange(20)
        ys = np.random.rand(20)
        cs = [c] * len(xs)
        ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

I've played around with the set_zorder method but to no avail.  Could someone please help me to diagnose and perhaps solve this problem?  Maybe this is only happening on my machine?  Many thanks.  Adrian

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this/14825951#14825951 tldr: artists are rendered one at a time, a single artist is always either above or below another artist.  You have to go to great length to get layering.