# How to create graph where a geometry be surrounded by particles using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using examples and documentation from [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html), I can create one figure with two graphs like [this](http://indraazimi.com/img/figure_1.png). On the left, it is geometry graph and on the right, it is particles graph. What I want to create actually is a graph where the geometry will be surrounded by particles. How to do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

vx = []
vy = []
vz = []
ins = open( "vertex.txt", "r" )
for line in ins:
    nilai = line.strip().split()
    vx.append(float(nilai[1]))
    vy.append(float(nilai[2]))
    vz.append(float(nilai[3]))

triangles = []
ins = open( "iface4.txt", "r" )
for line in ins:
    nilai = line.strip().split()
    t1 = int(nilai[1])
    t2 = int(nilai[2])
    t3 = int(nilai[3])
    if t1!=0 and t2!=0 and t3!=0:
        triangles.append([t1, t2, t3])

ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d') #ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(vx, vy, vz, triangles=triangles, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)

vx = []
vy = []
vz = []
ins = open( "particle.txt", "r" )
for line in ins:
    nilai = line.strip().split()
    vx.append(float(nilai[0]))
    vy.append(float(nilai[1]))
    vz.append(float(nilai[2]))

ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(vx, vy, vz, c='b', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens if you just remove the second `ax = fig.add_subplot(...)` line?

Comment: It's awesome. Thanks for your clue!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this/14825951#14825951 <- you are going to run into other problems later due to the way that mpl draws.

Answer (score 0):

I think BrenBarn is correct, if you just remove this line:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
```

then the particle scatter plot will be on the same axis. You're reusing your variable name 'ax' in the code, which probably is what is confusing you.