# Matplotlib - Drawing text behind Poly3DCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw some text behind a `Poly3DCollection` object, unfortunately using the `zorder` keyword doesn't seem to produce the effect requested.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show

canvas = figure()
axes = Axes3D(canvas)
axes.text(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 'I would like to be behind!', 'x', zorder=0)

x = [0, 1, 1, 0]
y = [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5]
z = [0, 0, 1, 1]
axes.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([zip(x, y, z)], zorder=1))
show()
```

[image: Matplotlib - Poly3DCollection - Text]

Comment: This is a limitation of the 3D rendering in mpl.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this/14825951#14825951 for a much longer explanation.  Axes3D ignores zorder and draws artists in the order it thinks they should be.

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately it is what I was thinking.