# Angle between intersecting planes drawn with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, plane

I need to produce a plot with intersecting planes, similar to the one presented in the question: [How to draw intersecting planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14824893/1391441). The accepted answer in that question is a great piece of code by [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell) (code is below).

In that code, a var `angle` is used which apparently controls the angle between each planes. For small values it certainly behaves like that, but for larger values it does not.

For example, these are the results for the values `angle = 0.25, 0.5, 1, 5, 50, 100`.

[image]

The variable obviously has an effect over the angle between the planes, but it also controls the extension of the inclined plane. At first I though `angles` was expressed in radians, but it is not. It's also not expressed in degrees, as seen in the image above where it never seems to reach a 90º angle between the planes.

The questions are then: what is that variable doing?, and: how can I control the angle between the planes?

---

**Code:**

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

dim = 10

# Define x,y plane.
X, Y = np.meshgrid([-dim, dim], [-dim, dim])
Z = np.zeros((2, 2))

# Define inclined plane.
angle = 0.5  # <-- This is the variable
X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid([-dim, dim], [0, dim])
Z2 = Y2 * angle
X3, Y3 = np.meshgrid([-dim, dim], [-dim, 0])
Z3 = Y3 * angle

# Plot x,y plane.
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='gray', alpha=.5, linewidth=0, zorder=1)
# Plot top half of inclined plane.
ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2, color='blue', alpha=.5, linewidth=0, zorder=3)
# Plot bottom half of inclined plane.
ax.plot_surface(X2, Y3, Z3, color='blue', alpha=.5, linewidth=0, zorder=-1)

ax.set_xlim(-10., 10.)
ax.set_ylim(-10., 10.)
ax.set_zlim(-10., 10.)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is called `angle` is just a multiplier for the y-coordinate. So for small *angles* the result is the same, however, for a 90 degree rotation the factor would have to be infinity.

You can redefine the angle using the [tanget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent) and providing an input in radians:

```
angle = np.tan(pi * 0.25)
```

Now, you will see an actual rotation with a specified angle.

[image: pi*0.25] [image: pi*1/3]

---

a cleaner modification may be:

```
# Define inclined plane.
angle = pi * 0.5  # <-- This is the variable
X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid([-dim, dim], [0, dim])
Z2 = Y2 * np.tan(angle)
X3, Y3 = np.meshgrid([-dim, dim], [-dim, 0])
Z3 = Y3 * np.tan(angle)
```

Comment: Thanks Schorsch. A question: above you say that I could use `angle=np.tan(np.pi*0.5)` but below you say `angle=np.pi*0.5`. These are different equations, which one is it?

Comment: @Gabriel If you only want to change the `angle` line, use what I wrote first. However, strictly speaking that line uses tangent on an angle. So from a varibale naming and confusion approach, the second bit just specifies `angle` in radians. But then you need the tangent as a function for `Z2` and `Z3`. All just personal preference

Comment: Oh sorry Schorsch, I missed the modification you made on `Z2` and `Z3`, that's what got me confused. Thanks again!