# Python matplot3d - plot two sets of data on the same 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I`m trying to plot 2 sets of data on a single 3D plot.
What I expect to see is these two images on the same plot:
[image]

The plot I am looking for is this: [image]

I use Anaconda and Jupiter, matplotlib 1.5.1.

This is my code so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cop

class var1:
    def __init__(self,b1, b2):
        self.pt1 = copy.deepcopy(b1)       
        self.pt2 = copy.deepcopy(b2) 
        self.cords = (
            list(self.pt1 + [high]), # top-left
            list(self.pt2 + [high]), # top-right
            list(self.pt2 + [low]), # bottom-right 
            list(self.pt1 + [low]), # bottom-left
            )            
    def drawFunction(self):       
        dataSet1 = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([self.cords])
        dataSet1.set_color('firebrick')
        dataSet1.set_edgecolor('k')
        ax.add_collection3d(dataSet1)    #If you comment out this line- var2 will be shown. I`m trying to show one on top of the other
        var2(self.pt1, self.pt2, high, low).drawFunction()

class var2:
    def __init__(self,b1, b2, high, low):
        self.pt1 = copy.deepcopy(b1)       
        self.pt2 = copy.deepcopy(b2) 
        self.cords = (
            list(self.pt1 + [(high/2) + (high/4)]), # top-left
            list(self.pt2 +  [(high/2) + (high/4)]), # top-right
            list(self.pt2 +  [(high/2) - (high/4)]), # bottom-right 
            list(self.pt1 +  [(high/2) - (high/4)]), # bottom-left
            )       
    def drawFunction(self):
        dataSet2 = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([self.cords])
        dataSet2.set_color('cornflowerblue')
        dataSet2.set_edgecolor('k')
        ax.add_collection3d(dataSet2)

high = 500
low = 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

i = 0 
while i<4:
    if (i==0):
        p1 = [0,200]
        p2 = [0,0]
    if (i==1):
        p1 = [0,0]
        p2 = [200,0]
    if (i==2):
        p1 = [200,0]
        p2 = [200,200]
    if (i==3):
        p1 = [200,200]
        p2 = [0,200]

    var1(p1, p2).drawFunction()
    i = i+1

ax.set_xlim(0,200)
ax.set_ylim(0, 200)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please see the Edit part.

Comment: Code has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Note, that in the example code both the figures are present, you can see it by changing the code in the following way `Poly3DCollection([self.cords],alpha=0.5)`. It's just that the `add_collection3d` draws one over the other, so you don't see both.

I didn't find a way to beat it, but you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-intersecting-planes/14825951#14825951) for a possible workaround.

BTW, the code is missing `import copy` and `ax = a3.Axes3D(fig)` to work.