# Drawing the x,y,z-Plane instead of the normal grid

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I'd like to make a little 3D plot. For that, I'd like to just draw the x,y,z-axis and/or the x,y,z plane. Not like the normal grid which moves the planes to the "background".

Whats the best approach for that?

Comment: I think I remember seeing this question already been asked at some point. But I can't find it. I would suspect that it is not possible, but I can be wrong on that one.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to draw intersecting planes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14824893/190597)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for.  For example, "the x,y,z plane" is not a meaningful mathematical phrase.  It's also not clear to me what you mean by "background".. by background do you mean a Cartesian coordinate system?